# Particle Simulation does not correctly bake negative Frames?

Tags: geometry-nodes, particles, baking, shader-nodes, emission

**TLDR**
The baked Particles of my spinning Portal behave incorrectly in negative frames (frame -20 to 0) and the emission Shader of the particles which uses age & Lifetime to control the color is not working until frame 1.

**What i want to do & initial situation** 
I want to make a spinning portal like in doctor strange. For this I want to bake a particle simulation that starts at a negative frame as preroll for my Shot. The Portal is created in Geometrie nodes where i moved the keyframes for the spinn that it (should) start way before Frame 0. The portal is from a tutorial by "default cube" released one year ago (he uses a driver for the rotation, i changed it to numbers to be able to move the keyframes) (https://youtu.be/BSwhX-NDQ8o?si=y1W2ZxTyWGYyO-ok)

**What problem i'm facing** 
I am able to get a bake for the negative frames but the bake is behaving incorrectly in a few manners. I start the bake at Frame -20 where particles start appearing until frame -3. These particles look like they fell for a few frames due to their position but they are not moving at all between Frame 20 and -4. At frame -3 the particles jump up and form more tightly around the emitter and begin to fall (without spin) until frame 0. at frame -1 they jump back again, even more tightly, and begin to behave correctly gravity wise. on frame 0 or 1 the start to spin with the emitter - behaving correctly.

 
Additionally the shading is off. The particle age and particle lifetime drive the color and the luminance of the particles, the older the particle the darker the particle. The brightness only starts increasing on frame 1, before the particles are completely black even though my shader would never let them be black (maybe it's due to emission being 0), only dark orange.

**What i tried already** 
I have enabled "allow negative frames". I have set the start frame to negative and positive numbers. I have toggled the "use preview range" swatch icon on and off (above the timeline). I have cleared the cache and rebaked several times.

**What i want to achieve**
I want the Shader to show the correct emission, meaning the particles should glow at frame 1. I want the particles to bake in the negative frames so that they behave normally at frame 1, however, if the emission works i'm able to work around the baking problem/strange behaviour of the particles.

[image: Portal Screenshots]

Also i can't any more pictures to this question, it only displays the image reference text ([![Geo-Node Screenshot][1]][1]). Any idea why that would be?

Any help or advise is welcome! Thank you for your time and help! 
have a great day

Comment: Hi Marius, if you wanna have quick help and people don't wanna make ask in the comments, i would recommend providing your blend file because we have no idea what you did. thx.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the suggestion. Problem is the scene is a motion tracking scene with the portal appended from a different file. But i'm happy to provide the appended File with the Portal, this will however not contain the modifications i made to get it to start in the negative frames. What should i do in my situation? I also wanted to attach more screenshots of my geo-nodes and Shader but it would not let me as i mentioned at the bottom of my question.